# INNER JOIN with one single property column and one multi property column

Tags: mysql, join

I have three tables:

First consists of base items (table name : ITEMS)

```
| id | picture_id | name | other_columns |
```

Second consists of base element's properties (table name : ITEM_PROP)

```
| id | item_id | prop_id | prop_value |
```

Third contains info about files (table name : FILES)

```
| id | type | subdir | file_name |
```

I have build a query:

```
SELECT items.id, item.name, item_prop.prop_value, files.subdir,file.file_name 
FROM items LEFT JOIN items_prop 
ON items.id = item_prop.item_id 
LEFT JOIN FILES 
on item_prop.prop_value = files.id WHERE item_prop.prop_id = 2 
ORDER BY items.id
```

This will be a list of files linked with the each item.

> | id | name  | prop_value  | subdir       |   file_name     |
>
> | 1  | item #1 |      2      | 'res/aeb342' | 'item_pic1.jpg' |

Question: **Is it possible** to add items.picture_id in prop_value column and linked with it picture in the two other columns?

Example: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fd5663/9)

I want to select items.picture_id with files data in one query.
Somethink like this:

> 

```
SELECT 
  items.id, items.name, 
  item_prop.prop_value, 
  files.subdir, files.file_name 
FROM items 
LEFT JOIN item_prop ON items.id = item_prop.item_id 
LEFT JOIN files ON item_prop.prop_value = files.id
UNION 
SELECT 
    items.id, items.name, items.picture_id,
    files.subdir, files.file_name 
FROM items 
LEFT JOIN files ON items.picture_id = files.id
```

Comment: Can you add some sample data and desire output ?

Comment: have you added this columns in query ? if yes than what is the problem ?

Comment: Can you please share some sample data?

Comment: What would the output look like?

Comment: so, what is the problem with existing sql ?

Comment: Ravi, if it will be more properties, i need to write union query for each property